# Spring MVC jackson auto serialize?

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I would like to serialize an object with jackson in spring MVC.

I have a controller which returns an ObjectTest1 which has a property ObjectTest2.

```
public class ObjectTest1{
 private ObjectTest2;
 // setters getters...
}

public class ObjectTest2{
 private String value;
 // setters getters...
}

public @ResponseBody ObjectTest1 test() throws IOException ...
```

I have a mapper and I have a serializer for ObjectTest2 and I've annotated the ObjectTest1.getObjectTest2 method with @JsonSerialize(using = ObjectTest2.class).

It works correctly!
But I want to use this serializer in a lot of Object, not just in ObjectTest1.

What should I do to avoid put annotation every getter method? Can use spring this serializer automatically for all properites which is ObjectTest2?

**UPDATED:**

I've already use this in my code:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
```

In ajax response Objects generated correctly as json.
Maybe I should try to explain another way.

So.
I have these objects:

```
public class DTO{
  private InnerThing innerThing;

  @JsonSerialize(using=ThingSerializer.class)
  public InnerThing getThing(){...}
}

public class InnerThing{
  private String value;
}
```

Generated json looks like:

```
{"innerThing":{"value":"something"}}
```

Afther when I've written a serializer, json is:

```
{"innerThing":"something"}
```

It is OK, but to get the second version of json I must annotate the getInnerThing method in DTO class with @JsonSerialize...

I don't want to annotate all methods where I use InnerThing as a property.
So my question is, can spring auto serialize every property which type is InnerThing?

Comment: If Jackson is found by Spring 3 in classpath and you have `mvc:annotation-driven`, [Spring MVC automagically converts every `@ResponseBody` returned object](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-config-enable) - you don't need to use `@JsonSerialize`.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Spring will handle serialization and de-serialization of JSON automatically if you add Jackson to the classpath and you use either `<mvc:annotation-driven>` or `@EnableWebMvc`.

Links to the Spring Reference Docs:

Spring 3.0: [<mvc:annotation-driven>](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven)

Spring 3.1: [<mvc:annotation-driven> and @EnableWebMvc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable)

Answer (score 2):

You want Jackson to always use your custom JsonSerializer or JsonDeserializer to serialize/deserialize a specific type?

I ended up writing a custom Jackson module to let Jackson find serializers and deserializers that are Spring beans.
I am using Spring 3.1.2 and Jackson 2.0.6

Simplified version:

```
public class MyObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    @Autowired
    public MyObjectMapper(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        SpringComponentModule sm = new SpringComponentModule(applicationContext);
        registerModule(sm);
    }
}
```

Module:

```
public class SpringComponentModule extends Module {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public SpringComponentModule(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
    @Override public String getModuleName() {
        return "jackson-spring-component";
    }
    @Override public Version version() {
        return SpringComponentModuleVersion.instance.version();
    }
    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        context.addSerializers(new SpringComponentSerializers(this.applicationContext));
        context.addDeserializers(new SpringComponentDeserializers(this.applicationContext));
    }
}
```

ComponentSerializer class:

```
public class SpringComponentSerializers extends Serializers.Base {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public SpringComponentSerializers(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> findSerializer(SerializationConfig config, JavaType type, BeanDescription beanDesc) {
        Class<?> raw = type.getRawClass();
        Map<String,JsonSerializer> beanSet = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(JsonSerializer.class);
        for(String beanName : beanSet.keySet()) {
            JsonSerializer<?> serializer = beanSet.get(beanName);
            if(serializer.handledType().isAssignableFrom(raw)) {
                return serializer;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```